# SharePoint 2013 "search by path" or "search this site" with claims show no results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, claims-based-auth, enterprise-search, adfs

**My Problem:**

I cant use the Managed Attribute "Path" to search in a defined SiteCollection or Website or something else. And the "Search this Site" field on each site dosen't work too.

I've resetet the crawl index... maybe five or six times....

I've restartet the SearchServiceInstance... maybe three or four times...

**What I have done:**

I have a WebApplication with a HostNamed Site Collection with URL intranet.local:444 in zone **DEFAULT**. The **Default** Authentication Provider is NTLM.

Than I've extended this WebApplication on intranet.local:443 and added a second Authentication Provider (ADFS)  -> Both in Zone **INTRANET**

So what I have is:

intranet.local:444 -> NTLM -> Default Zone

intranet.local:443 -> ADSF -> Intranet Zone

Now I configured the search to crawl intranet.local:444 (because search cant auth. with claims and have to use NTLM). 
Than I added the Servername Mapping :444 to :443.

Everything work great **BUT I CANT SEARCH BY PATH**

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would download the search query tool from https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/

Then do a search for * and look in the primary results tab what the path property contains.

Additionally please assert in the search application search schema if the path managed property is queryable (I changed only added refineable):

[image: Path]

Comment: Thanks for the answer... but I have now the Solution! The trick is, that I have to fix the servername mapping in search administration! before I had https:// mysite.local.com:444 to https:// mysite.local.com -> but it have to be mysite.local.com:444 to https:// mysite.local.com!

Comment: @domsen123 you sould post this comment as an answer. I just had a very similar problem, and your solution worked!